# Does useEffect run twice in production?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, production-environment

The question is pretty straight forward.
I know that it is supposed to run twice in development to faster identify bugs.
But no I ask myself if I need to configure something so it does not happed in production when I deploy my NextJS app.

Here is the issue I am having. So I took some time off programming because of Uni. Now I am trying to fetch some data in useEffect right after render but can't get it to work right.

I could simply do:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/api/collection/getCollections`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => setData(data.collections))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, [])
```

Or something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        await fetch(`/api/collection/getCollections`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setData(data.collections)).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
    getData();
}, [])
```

Which is basically the same thing. But both runs twice and I get two API calls

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `next.config.js` file and make `reactStrictMode` equal `false`, then restart the node server. This is why your API gets called twice.

> React's Strict Mode is a **development** mode only feature for
> highlighting potential problems in an application. It helps to
> identify unsafe lifecycles, legacy API usage, and a number of other
> features(see [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/react-strict-mode)).

*So yes, it is only for **development** mode.*